# STRTOTIME take date and data from mysql and concatenate them on php

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, strtotime

I have 2 variables stored into `mysql`:

1. campaign_date  `Format: d/m/Y`
2. campaign_time `Format: 24Hr`

How could I concatenate them into one single variable like this:

```
2015-06-16T18:30
```

I tried with:

```
$new_datetime=$campaign_date.'T'.$campaign_time;
```

But it's not working

Comment: unless there is a giant flashing window with `but it's not working` I'd say you should give us more info

Comment: use php date() or equial mysql function to tranfer the date in the format you need

Comment: Start storing dates in Y-m-d format in `DATE` field type. I really don't understand why would any1 choose string/varcgar field type for custom date format...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

(For the first date you have to change `/` to `-` so you can use `date()` and you can change the order of `d/m/Y` to `Y-m-d`, after that it's a simple concatenation with the time at the end)

```
<?php

    $campaign_date = "16/12/2014";  //Data from DB
    $campaign_time = "18:00";       //Data from DB

    echo $new_datetime = date("Y-m-d", strtotime(str_replace("/", "-", $campaign_date))) . "T" . date("H:i", strtotime($campaign_time));

?>
```

Output:

```
2014-12-16T18:00
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, just last question: I need to use this constant $new_datetime into a div: 'code'<div class="soon" id="my-soon-counter"
     data-due=$new_datetime;    
</div>'code' How to accomplished? dumb question from newbie :)

Comment: @drhouse How do you mean `constant`? Like do you just need it in this div?

Comment: I need to use the new $new_datetime into a div as in my example above

Comment: Then this should work for you: `<div class="soon" id="my-soon-counter" data-due="<?= $new_datetime; ?>"></div>`

Answer (score 1):

Try it,i tested it myself.

```
$db_date = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($db_date));
$db_time = date("h:i:s",strtotime($db_time));
echo $db_date.'T'.$db_time;
```

Comment: OP gets the data from his database!

Comment: @Rahamsher i need this format as output 2015-06-16T18:30

Comment: @drhouse I think my answer should help you!

Comment: @Rizier123 nw check it please.

Comment: @RahamSher won't work! The format is: `d/m/Y`! `date()` doesn't accept that!

Comment: @Rizier123 if you dont need seconds then remove the 's' from db_time.